# adding a first difference column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with two columns `date` and `data`. I want to take the first difference of the data column and add it as a new column.

It seems that `df.set_index('date').shift()` or `df.set_index('date').diff()` give me the desired result. However, when I try to add it as a new column, I get NaN for all the rows.

How can I fix this command:

```
df['firstdiff'] = df.set_index('date').shift()
```

to make it work?

Comment: Sorry what's wrong with just assigning `df['firstdiff'] =df['date'].shift()`? I don't understand why you're setting the index here?

Comment: @EdChum oh I just started using pandas so I was just following some blog posts here and there. but your solution worked nicely. thanks!